# Could you help me finding some less colloquial equivalent to highlighted phrases of this speech

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning

> Today **I want to be able to** give you some good tips on parallel parking. It's part of your road test. It's something you need to learn. For most new drivers it's real difficult, because they're not able to judge angles. And parallel parking is all about angles. I'll take you through a typical parking, **I'll take you through how I teach it** , and maybe that'll help you in passing your road test. The first thing **you want to do** is you want to pull over over and **you want to** stop alongside a parked car. Typically, an inspector will give you a command to pull over, stop next to the red or blue car. **You're just going to** pull over, put your blinker on to the right, and pull over even with that car.

- taken from a series of videos teaching driving

  1. Why did the man use  **be able** in his speech? What is the difference between **be able** and **I would like to** or **I want** ? I mean what the listener should make of  **I want to be able to give you ...**  . Why did not he say **I want to give you...** ?
  2. When he says **I'll take you through a typical parking** , I get the meaning of **take one through** ,It means **I am going to teach you** , isn't it? But my real concern is what the second **I'll take you through** means, while saying **I'll take you through how I teach it** . Perhaps it doesn't mean **I will teach you that how I teach it !** , does it?
  3. The man always says **the first thing you want to do** . Why does not he say **the first thing you should do** , **the first thing you need to do** ? What are the diffrences in meaning? Isn't it unnatural saying **you want to do** ?
  4. In the last sentence he says **You're just going to pull over**, is the use of **going to** just weakening would and will? I think here it means something else. I think it means **you just want to or you just start**

Comment: The way the person in the video is speaking is very colloquial and I'm not sure that a thorough analysis is going to be helpful in learning to speak English well.

Comment: @ColleenV - I will appreciate your help just converting those colloquials to more standard English so that it would be easy to get for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Having said that speaking English well is not my concern now. I just want to tramslate the text for my friend learning driving in my first language, the text is so informal and difficult to translate. If it had been even academic, it would have been much easier, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: Translating from a video is so difficult because not many people use a script. Here is my interpretation:
Today, I will demonstrate some techniques for passing the parallel parking section of your road test. For many new drivers, this part of the test is difficult because they haven't learned a skill important to parallel parking - how to judge the angles. I will show you step by step how to parallel park in a typical situation. Usually, an inspector will tell you to pull over and stop next to a parked car. Remember to put your blinker on and then pull over even with that car.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, I think your instincts are accurate.

1. Precisely, **I want to give you...** is exactly what he means.
2. Slightly confusing, but I think he means "I am going to give you an example of a typical parking scenario, as I teach it." Both sentences really mean the same thing.
3. As with the rest of your examples, he's speaking very informally. Yes, **the first thing you should do** is a good understanding.
4. Not sure if I follow your meaning here. I think he's using "just" to imply that the steps you will follow are simple. So yes, I guess he's using it to weaken the sentence. (Where do "would" and "will" come from?) The suggestion that these steps are simple or basic is to offset the difficulty he mentions in the fourth sentence. **edit**: fixated on the wrong word. He's laying out a set of steps - "You will: [step 1], [step 2], [step 3]." but phrased in a very informal manner.